# Can I check ongoing call status in Twilio with one API call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I need to know how many active calls are in process at any particular moment. So, that means calls can either be: *ringing* or *in-progress* but, for this application, I am also including *queued*.

```
$activecalltype = array("queued", "ringing", "in-progress");
```

Can I make one call to the api instead of 3 i.e.:

```
foreach ($twilioclient->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
          "Status" => 'queued',
          "From" => $callerid,
          "StartTime" => $thisday
          )) as $call) ...
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
          foreach ($twilioclient->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
          "Status" => 'queued',
          "Status" => 'ringing',
          "Status" => 'in-progress',
          "From" => $callerid,
          "StartTime" => $thisday
          )) as $call) ...
```

But, this example does not work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't specify multiple status values in a single API call. It has to be one of the supported values.

You can however pull the whole list of calls in a single API call, irrespective of their status, and filter the result in code.